# Extracting a year based on two different dates MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has two date formats. The first is "2010.10.24 11:59" and the second is "1/19/2011 10:59:52 AM".

My query:

```
UPDATE sms_clean
   SET yr = year(time)
 WHERE year(time) <> NULL
```

Will get the year up to the second date format.

This returns error 1292.

Should I write a second query to solve this? How do I avoid an error?

When I try adding an or statement with the following code:

```
UPDATE sms_clean
   SET yr = year(time), send_year = year(str_to_date(time, '%m/%d/%Y %i:%l'))
 WHERE year(time) <> NULL 
    OR year(str_to_date(time, '%m/%d/%Y %i:%l AM')) <> NULL
```

I get error 1411 where MySQL doesn't seem to be taking the year from year(time). Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest adding a proper datetime column and normalizing the dates once.

Comment: How would I go about normalizing the dates, is it possible to extract just the year? Can I use Or statements in SET?

Answer (score 0):

`2010.10.24 11:59` is in [a format MySQL understands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html). `"1/19/2011 10:59:52 AM"` is not. Use [`coalesce`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp) to try different methods of parsing; that's the SQL equivalent of `this || that`.

```
update sms_clean
set yr = coalesce(
  year(time),
  year(str_to_date(time, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'))
);
```

However, rather than dealing with oddly formatted datetimes and making separate columns for the year, normalize them once as a proper [`datetime` column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html). Then they can be indexed and easily queried.

```
alter table sms_clean add column time_normalized datetime;

update sms_clean
set time_normalized = coalesce(
  str_to_date(time, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'),
  time
)
where time_normalized is null;
```

Then check for anything which didn't convert by looking for rows with a null `time_normalized`, figure out the `str_to_date` pattern, and fix them, too.

Once everything is normalized, delete `time`, rename `time_normalized`, and index it.

```
alter table sms_clean drop column time;
alter table sms_clean rename column time_normalized time;
create index sms_clean_time on sms_clean(time);
```

Now if you want the year, just ask for the year.

```
select * from sms_clean where year(time) = 2020;
```

Note: [`time` is a MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-T) and using it as a column name can cause ambiguities. I would recommend naming the column something else like `sent_at` or `received_at`.